# Is there any reliable way to verify a u-boot.bin file before Flashing it to a board?

Tags: linux, embedded, upgrade, u-boot

I've recently bricked one of my embedded Marvell ARM systems, was upgrading to a new u-boot.bin over TFTP from within u-boot via the bubt tool.  bubt fetched the image, burned it to Flash, didn't give any output saying there was anything wrong.

On reboot the system got stuck in an endless loop on the primary bootloader.

Therefore my question is, does the u-boot.bin file have any inbuilt checksums, magic header numbers etc. that could be used to validate the file is good before burning it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. `.bin` is a raw image of u-boot.

You could do it yourself encapsulating the raw file into a image file, e.g.: with a file header the hold a CRC32, length of file and so on.

Take notes that the standard u-boot upgrade procedure delete the existant one before to flash the new one. If something happend between cancellation and re-flash the board will be corrupted.

BTW are you sure that your problem belong to a wrong write to memory, and not to a bugged u-boot?

Comment: I wonder why they didn't encapsulate the u-boot binary in a header like uImage does?  Yes, I am fairly sure I had a corrupt u-boot, after re-installing the soft-fp cross compiler I got it working.